# How to change selected icon image in BottomNavigationView in android?

Tags: android, material-design

I have inflated menu_main.xml to BottomNavigationView and now i want to change the icons in BottomNavigation when we select an item .

Comment: Use a [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) for the icons

Comment: sorry it did'nt help me

Comment: Did you actually go through the link? It is exactly what you need like the answer given below states

Comment: Thank u very much now i implemented correctly and it works.

Answer (score 7):

If above solution is not working for you to change selected item icon then add below line to your code:

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

This will disable color tint effect of selected item icon and change the icon as per your selector drawable.

I had the same problem. I have added selector drawable for changing icon of BottomNavigationView item when its checked/selected.

Answer (score 3):

Create item called selector in `drawable` folder and icon can be changed  according to the selected state of the widget used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_green" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Use `selector` as a menu icon in navigation

Comment: can u please tell me where i have to use this selector.xml

Comment: Set the background of the icon to the above xml

Answer (score 1):

You have to save this in the `res/drawable` directory.

And use it as follows:

ex: bottomNavigationMenu.xml
...

```
android:icon="@drawable/your_selector"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Xml of Bottom NavigationView 

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottom_navigation"
                        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottom_navigation"
                        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

    Bottm Navigation Menu 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/selecter_tab_home"
            android:title="@string/text_home"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_explore"
            android:icon="@drawable/selector_tab_explore"
            android:title="@string/text_explore"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/selector_tab_profile"
            android:title="@string/text_profile"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    </menu>

Selector of home menu you can put next two same also with differnt drawable file 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_home" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_home_fill" android:state_checked="true"/>

</selector>
```